# Miva Merchant Integration

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart, miva

I have a prospective client that currently uses Miva Merchant as their e-commerce solution.  They would like me to add functionality that I have done before with Magento.  I know that Miva uses its own proprietary scripting language, but how similar is this to other languages?  How steep is the learning curve to be able to modify core functionality of the shopping cart?

Are they're any resources out there to try developing for Miva without purchasing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download Miva Mia here: http://www.mivamerchant.com/products/mia/

you will also ned MySQL and the database connector to develop locally. If you are familiar with PHP you should be able to pick up on miva script fairly easy.
Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out the Miva Merchant forums for help when you get stuck plus tips & tricks. It is very active, you can find the forums here: http://extranet.mivamerchant.com/forums/